# Java StringBuilder with printf. Equivalent String.format

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, string.format

I am using StringBuilder to build a ver long query.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("select * from x where name = %s'");
String.format(sb.toString, "John");
```

What would be equivalent to something like this? Or is this actually the right way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you are attempting to build a String for `SQL`. `PreparedStatement` should be used instead for this purpose.

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = 
        connection.prepareStatement("select * from x where name = ?");
preparedStatement.setString(1, "John");
```

*Edit:*

Given that you're using `EntityManager`, you can use its equivalent `setParameter`

```
Query q = 
 entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from x where name = ?", MyClass.class);
q.setParameter(1, "John");
```

Comment: Same answer, But I was too quick

Comment: @nelsonjuan What are trying to do here by appending ?

Comment: @Ruchira I am actually using javax.persistence.EntityManager to take care of the database. I am preparing the String to em.createNativeQuery(sb.toString(), SomeClass.class).getResultList()

Comment: @nelsonjuan You can set parameters for `EntityManager's` native queries using `setParameter`

Answer (score 1):

This may help you. where the `con` is connection

```
    PreparedStatement preStatement = con.prepareStatement("select * from x where name = ?");
    preStatement.setString(1, "John");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using SQL, for a general formatted append, could use `Formattor`'s `format()` method.

e.g

```
/**
 * Generate a string that also contains data list.
 *
 * @return
 */
public String toStringWithDataList() {
    List<T> list = toList();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(getClass().getName());
    Formatter fm = new Formatter(sb);

    sb.append(toString()).append(System.lineSeparator()); // basic info,

    // value list,
    if (size > 0) {
        sb.append("list = ");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            fm.format("\n\t[%d]-th: %s", i, list.get(i));
        }
        sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```